# jQuery: Cannot initialize event listener from class definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, event-handling, listener

I am creating a class:

```
var MyClass;
(function($) {
    MyClass = new function() {

        $('a').off('click');
        $('a').on( 'click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

When clicking on a link, a full request is still being issued.

When pasting ...

```
$('a').on( 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

... in my console and retrying, everything works as expected.

Is it possible that I am not able to initialize an event listener from within a class definition. If so, how would I initialize my event listener then?

Comment: Probably initializing your class before those elements exist. That is a very strange class definition also

Comment: I hope this is a gross simplification of your class definition, otherwise it seems like there's no point to the class.

Comment: You either need to run this code inside `$(document).ready()` or you need to use event delegation to bind to dynamically-created elements.

Comment: @Barmar It is, it's just supposed to exemplify the problem.

Comment: @Barmar Your solution works. Don't know why I did not think of this myself ...

Comment: Just curious: which one?

Comment: And of course,the problem has nothing to do with running your code in a class definition.

Comment: @Barmar Running the code on the `ready` event.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
$('body').off('click','a');
```

or:

```
$(document).off('click','a');
```

if you init your class before dom is ready.

Short way for your class:

```
var MyClass = (function($){
    // your code here
    // or with init method
    function init () {
        $('body').off('click','a');
    }
    return {init : init};
})(jQuery);
```

Than run dom ready:

```
$(function(){
    MyClass.init()
});
```

Comment: +1 for proposing the `init` function. However, the problem has already been solved - read up on the comments